# Microphone in a webcam is not recognized by some communication apps

Tags: audio, windows-11, skype, microphone

I have a Logitech C270 HD Webcam with a microphone in it. It used to work fine, but recently (could be some Windows updates?) the microphone stopped working with some communication apps.

It works fine with Google Meet and Microsoft Teams. It does not with Skype and Telegram. The camera, however, works everywhere.

What could be the cause of the issue?

OS Windows 11 v.10.0.22621. All available updates are installed.

---

Just a supporting fact, that could be relevant - or not. I bought a standard PC microphone and plugged it into the onboard Realtek audio panel. It didn't work at all.
Also, I use an external (USB) Behringer audio card. It works fine for the output, but plugging the microphone in it doesn't work either. Unplugging the external audio (to check for conflicts) also didn't help.

Comment: @harrymc Although what you suggest here can't hurt it won't fix it for sure. The OP can't use inputs neither on the onboard sound chip -nor- on the external USB card. Knowing this we must conclude this has absolutely nothing to do with the Logitech camera *per se* but something else very wrong with the OS.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Why would an OS problem manifest itself selectively, working correctly for Google Meet and Microsoft Teams but not for Skype and Telegram.

Comment: @harrymc I don't know and I used "OS problem" as a placeholder for whatever the software problem that affects multiple programs but now a few others. What it certainly has nopthing to do with is with the camera itself.